# CUDA kernel call in a simple sample

Tags: cuda

It's the first parallel code of  *cuda by example* .

Can any one describe me about the kernel call : <<< N , 1 >>>

This is the code with important points :

```
#define N   10

__global__ void add( int *a, int *b, int *c ) {
    int tid = blockIdx.x;    // this thread handles the data at its thread id
    if (tid < N)
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
}

int main( void ) {
    int a[N], b[N], c[N];
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    // allocate the memory on the GPU
    // fill the arrays 'a' and 'b' on the CPU
    // copy the arrays 'a' and 'b' to the GPU

    add<<<N,1>>>( dev_a, dev_b, dev_c );

    // copy the array 'c' back from the GPU to the CPU
    // display the results
    // free the memory allocated on the GPU

    return 0;
}
```

Why it used of `<<< N , 1 >>>` that it means we used of N blocks and 1 thread in each block ?? since we can write this `<<< 1 , N >>>` and used 1 block and N thread in this block for more optimization.

Comment: There is no particular reason. It's one of the first examples in the book trying to explain GPU Vector Sums. Optimal performance or any such concept is hardly on their mind at that point. It's a simple illustrative example. That's all. As the objective in the beginning states "You will write your first parallel code with CUDA C".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this little example, there is no particular reason (as Bart already told you in the comments). But for a larger, more realistic example you should always keep in mind that the number of threads per block is limited. That is, if you use N = 10000, you could not use `<<<1,N>>>` anymore, but `<<<N,1>>>` would still work.

Comment: There are limitations of grid size, too.

Comment: @chaohuang Yes, there are limitations too - I didn't mention this because I didn't want to make my reply too confusing, but of course you are right, this is an important fact! However, the maximum grid size is much larger than the number of threads per grid block.

Comment: Excuse me. If I want to use `<<<1,N>>>` and N is smaller than the block limitation , I must use `threadIdx` instead of `blockIdx` ? and another question : If i want to use `<<<2 , N/2>>>` , can any one help me to write add function ?

Comment: @mehD Yes, you would have to use `threadIdx` instead if `blockIdx` for `<<<1,N>>>`. For your example `<<<2, N/2>>>` you can compute the index like this: `uint idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;`. However, you always have to check the bounds of your indices: If N is an odd number, e.g. 5, you would get `<<<2,2>>>` (=4) because of the rounding. If you round up, you would get `<<<2,3>>>` (=6). In this case, you have to check the index in the kernel (e.g. `if( idx >= 5 ) return;`). Have a look at the examples in the Nvidia GPU Computing SDK, they are really helpful and instructive!